# How to make 'ng serve' work with Custom Angular Library?

Tags: angular

I have a project with two Angular applications. The applications have a lot in common, so I've decided to create an Angular Library with the common code. Now I have an Angular workspace with two applications and a library.

This library is built with ng build to some local folder and then it is linked to the common node_modules with 'ng link'. VSCode gives hint on the library when I code the applications. I can build the applications with 'ng build'. But each time I run 'ng serve' on the application and try to rebuild the library I have the following error in 'ng serve'

```
ERROR in ./Angular/Commons/target/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/vmig-angular-commons.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\Angular\Commons\target\__ivy_ngcc__\fesm2015\vmig-angul r-commons.js' 
at Object.openSync (fs.js:458:3)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:360:35)
at Storage.provideSync (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:109:13) 
at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:289:32)
at Observable._subscribe (G:\\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:36:51) 
at Observable._trySubscribe (G:\\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
at Observable.subscribe (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:25:20)
at SyncDelegateHost.read (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:48:21)
at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:166:44)
at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:43:54)
at processResource (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
at iteratePitchingLoaders (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
at runLoaders (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2) 
at NormalModule.doBuild (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
at NormalModule.build (G:\Projects\Vmig.Expert\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
```

I use Angular 10 on a WIndows machine. Is there any way to make ng serve work with a library?

As I've understood folder **ivy_ngcc** initially created by 'ng serve', it does not try to rebuild it. But when I run building of the library this directory os deleted.

Comment: Does dropping node_modules and then `npm install` solve this?

Comment: No. I can rerun ng serve. ng serve starts and compiles everything well. But when I run ng build for the library I have the same error.